# Constructing commandline flags for an external program out of bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I've got an array of filenames I'd like to be ignored by `stow`, for example

```
IGNORES=('post_install\.sh' 'dummy')
```

(actually, that list isn't fixed but read from a file and will not always have the same length, so hardcoding like below won't work).

I form commandline flags out of the array like so

```
IGNORES=("${IGNORES[@]/#/--ignore=\'}")
IGNORES=("${IGNORES[@]/%/\'}")
```

When I do

```
stow -v "${IGNORES[@]}" -t $home $pkg
```

however, the ignores are not respected by stow, but it doesn't complain about invalid arguments either. Directly writing

```
stow -v --ignore='post_install\.sh' --ignore='ignore' -t $home $pkg
```

does work though.

What is the difference between these two ways of passing the `--ignore` flags, any ideas how to fix the issue? To my understanding, `"${IGNORES[@]}"` should evaluate to one word per array element and have the intended effect (I tried removing the quotes and indexing the array with `*`, too, but to no avail).

Thanks!

Comment: Escaping the `.` in `post_install.sh` would be unnecessary but harmless if you weren't otherwise quoting the filename; inside quotes, you are adding a literal backslash to the name.

Comment: That's one further thing I need to verify. `man stow` says the names are interpreted as perl regexes that need to match at the end of the file name, so I think that I need to escape the dot in order ot get the pattern right (although a dot would of course match any character including a dot, but that's not really what I want).

Comment: Ah, yes, that's different.

Answer (score 1):

So while writing the post, I came across the solution: The single quotes I added here

```
IGNORES=("${IGNORES[@]/#/--ignore=\'}")
IGNORES=("${IGNORES[@]/%/\'}")
```

became part of the file names to ignore, and indeed a file named `'ignore'` would be skipped; doing only

```
IGNORES=("${IGNORES[@]/#/--ignore=}")
```

has the desired effect. I still need to check how this copes with spaces in the array elements, but my guess is that it works just fine since the necessity of quoting words with spaces only stems from splitting a complete commandline into words like

```
stow -v --ignore='the file' -t $home $pkg
```

vs

```
stow -v --ignore=the file -t $home $pkg
```

which is not a problem for the above and `"${IGNORES[@]}"` gets the words just right.

Comment: Quoting the array expansion is the correct way to protect whitespace in the array elements; indeed, it's the rationale for adding arrays to the language.